# How to generate XML data in Oracle which has Empty string as an attribute

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I want to generate an XML element using Oracle's XML documentation generation support features that looks like this

```
<Example Attr=""></Example>
```

Attr is an attribute of element Example and has a value of empty string "".

When I tried to generate an XML Element using Oracle's XML functions, I couldn't generate an XML element which has an attribute whose value is an empty string.

```
select XMLELEMENT("hello", xmlattributes('' as  "Max"))  from  dual
```

The result of the above query is

```
<hello></hello>
```

Note: there is no space between the single quotes for Max attribute.

However my requirement is

```
<hello Max=""></hello>     -- there is no space between the double quotes.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're aware, for XMLAtttribute ["if the value_expr is null, then no attribute is created for that value expression"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions242.htm#SQLRF06168).

You can work around this with [InsertChildXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB4289) but it isn't terribly pretty:

```
select insertchildxml(xmlelement("hello"), '/hello', '@Max', null) from dual;

INSERTCHILDXML(XMLELEMENT("HELLO"),'/HELLO','@MAX',NULL)                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<hello Max=""/>
```

... and as you can see it collapses an empty node, but that's only a potentially issue if you want this to look exactly as you showed - it's valid XML still. There is [an even uglier way around that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7976567/266304) if you really need to.

That also suggests an alternative to @smnbbrv's `replace`:

```
select updatexml(xmlelement("hello", xmlattributes('$$IMPOSSIBLE-VALUE$$' as  "Max")),
  '/hello[@Max="$$IMPOSSIBLE-VALUE$$"]/@Max', null) from dual;

UPDATEXML(XMLELEMENT("HELLO",XMLATTRIBUTES('$$IMPOSSIBLE-VALUE$$'AS"MAX")),'/HEL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<hello Max=""/>
```

which might be easier if your max attribute value is coming from data as you can NVL it to the impossible value. I'm not a fan of using magic values though really.

Comment: @user445, if this solves your problem, you should mark this as accepted. Everybody will know, that this issue is done and Alex is happy with some reputation points. Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo. Accepted! Thank you :)

Comment: @Shnugo this is a bit unfair to apply pressure on the people by pushing your opinion. You should have posted this as a comment on a question and not on an answer

Comment: @user445 could you comment why did you choose exactly this answer as a correct one?

Comment: You don't need to publicly justify your choice; but [follow the help center guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and choose the best solution to your problem (or wait for other answers; there may still be other ways to do this). ['Best' is subjective](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276602/266304) of course, but that's partly the point, it's up to you - don't be pressured to accept or even upvote an answer (even mine!)

Comment: @smnbbrv, you are right. Actually when I wrote this I hadn't seen, that user445 commented your answer with the same "solves my problem". I'm one of your upvoters anyway :-)

Comment: Hey guys, this is the first time I am accepting an answer.  I didn't know I have to accept an answer in the first place until @shnugo let me know about it. I just upvoted the answer. Both the posted solutions are interesting ways to solve this problem in my opinion.Also I found we can tag only one answer as the best answer for acceptance. So I just went ahead with Alex Poole's solution.

Answer (score 3):

What about setting the property value to some impossible value and then replace it with the value you need (so, empty string in your case)?

```
select replace(
  XMLELEMENT("hello", xmlattributes('$$IMPOSSIBLE-VALUE$$' as  "Max")).getStringVal(),
  '$$IMPOSSIBLE-VALUE$$'
)
from  dual;
```

I assume you anyway in the end need the string value, so even if this `XMLELEMENT` is just an example of the problem and you have a biiiig XML generated, you still can generate it first and then, finally, replace all the values with one command as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach (you write the source attribute instead of the "null"). This way, you don't have to search for some overall impossible value, it's enough to be impossible for that attribute.

`select
  replace(XMLELEMENT("hello", xmlattributes(nvl(null,' ') as  "Max")).getstringval(),
         'Max=" "',
         'Max=""') 
 from dual`

Answer (score 0):

I used updatexml() similar to A. Poole's example to create an empty string

```
set serveroutput on
 DECLARE
   xa xmltype;
   xb xmltype;
 BEGIN
   xa  := xmltype('<surfbreaks>'||
     '<break lineNum="0" recordtype="empty">d street </break>'||
     '<break lineNum="0" recordtype="empty">recordtype="empty" </break>'||
     '</surfbreaks>');

  dbms_output.put_line ('Before:');
  dbms_output.put_line (xa.getclobval);

  select UPDATEXML(xa, '//@recordtype', '') into xb from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line ('After:');
  dbms_output.put_line (xb.getclobval);
END; /
```